# MySQL - Comparing start and end date

Tags: php, mysql

For a school assignment I have to run a couple of queries in MySQL workbench.

One of the questions are as followed: How many employees have worked exactly 1 day for department no d001.

Now, I am a complete beginner with MySQL, and I have been searching around here and trough google but I couldn't find what syntax to use.

At this point I have the following syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM employees.dept_emp WHERE dept_no = 'd001';
```

The above syntax searches in the right department but now I have to make it so that it searches for employees that worked exactly 1 day for the company.

I have the following columns in the database:

```
emp_no, dept_no, from_date, to_date
```

I figure I should add an `AND` function with a function that compares the from and to date with a maximum variation of 1. But I haven't figured out how to do this...

Excuse my vague explanation, again, I am very new to MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mysql DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) to find the no. of day between two dates

```
SELECT * FROM employees.dept_emp
WHERE DATEDIFF(to_date, from_date) = 1

DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
```

expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.